# Pip install python modules easy

Tags: python, module, installation, pip

I am looking for an easy way to install/uninstall Python modules and found pip. 
Where does pip install to?
I installed as an example "linkify" and it supposed to work but I didnt find it in the sitepackages.
With videodownloader I had a permission denied issue at usr/local/bin.
So I lost my hopes again to find something easy. 
Is there a python modules installation for dummies.

Comment: It installs to the default "site-packages" (maybe you are looking at the wrong place). Depending on your OS it is possible that executable scripts are copied to /usr/local/bin. Usually you need su to install via PIP. Have a look at virtualenv if you want to use a specific location for installed packages (but PIP should provide a option for this, too).

Comment: Look in the log from `pip install --log=xx.log` [--no-dependencies] packagename-or-dir-or-tar.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setuptools, http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools includes the EasyInstall tool.

Check out http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html#downloading-and-installing-a-package to see how to use it.

Once you get that installed it should be ... easy.

Comment: Isn't pip usually recommended over easy_install?

Comment: If a permission issue stumped him, then easier is the only way to go, even if pip is 'better' in some senses.